# How do you Stop / Start Services on 140+ servers quickly?

Tags: powershell, service, scripting

We have over 140+ servers and when we need to perform an upgrade we need to stop 10 different services on each server before we can perform an upgrade. What is the fastest way to turn off all the services we require on all the servers ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) and the `-AsJob` switch.

Answer (score 0):

I was just searching for something similar and if this help you out man, that's great!

```
$Servers = Get-Content c:\serverlist.txt

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ScriptBlock { 

    if ((Get-Service -Name BITS).Status -e "Running") {

        Stop-Service -Name SERVICENAME
    }
}
```

This would need a file name serverlist.txt with the names of the servers on it listed only one on each line and it being located in C:\, you can also name whatever you want and place it wherever, just change the path.